# Не выводятся данные из таблицы: ошибка mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u225572694/public_html/articles.php on line 4

<?php
include("blocks/bd.php");/*Соединяемся с базой данных*/
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title,meta_d,meta_k,text FROM settings WHERE page='articles'",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="<? echo $myrow['meta_d']; ?>">
<meta name="keywords" content="<? echo $myrow['meta_k']; ?>">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<title><? echo $myrow['title']; ?></title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<table width="690" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="main_border">

<!--Подключаем шапку сайта-->
<? include ("blocks/header.php"); ?>

    <td><table width="690" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
<!--Подключаем левый блок сайта-->      
<? include ("blocks/lefttd.php"); ?>
        <td valign="top">
          <p><? echo $myrow['text']; ?>          </p>

<?
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT id,title,description,author,date FROM articles",$db);
$myrow =  mysql_fetch_array ($result);

do {

printf ("<table align='center' class='lesson'>

         <tr>
         <td class='lesson_title'>
         <p class='lesson_name'><a href='view_articles.php?id=%s'>%s</a></p>
         <p class='lesson_adds'>Дата добавления: %s</p>
         <p class='lesson_adds'>Автор статьи: %s</p></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
         <td>%s</td>
         </tr>

         </table><br><br>", $myrow["id"], $myrow["title"], $myrow["date"], $myrow["author"], $myrow["description"]);
}

while ($myrow =  mysql_fetch_array ($result));

?>

          <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
<!--Подключаем нижний графический элемент-->  
<? include ("blocks/footer.php"); ?>  
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Алексей31, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

А код в студию? У вас ошибка - не то в функцию передали.
Смотрим тут: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php.
Получается что

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title,meta_d,meta_k,text FROM settings WHERE page='articles'",$db);
```

возвращает FALSE. Причин тому может быть множество:
 - некорректно составлен запрос;
 - нет прав.

Сделай вот так:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title,meta_d,meta_k,text FROM settings WHERE page='articles'",$db) || die(mysql_error());
```

и посмотри, что вернет. )

Comment: Что за $db, для чего это у вас?

Comment: $db - необязательный параметр, указывающий на соединение с базой.